# What coordinate system to use for the position vector when finding the Electric Field or Field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

Good day all,

I have seen example problems regarding line charges that will use the position vector r in rectangular, cylindrical and spherical coordinates.

I know the following position vectors are:

**Rectangular: $r=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}$**

**Cylindrical: $r=\rho\hat{\rho }+z\hat{z}$**

**Spherical: $r=r\hat{r }$**

How do I know which coordinate system to use for a given situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these, and as long as you are consistent, it will always be a correct representation of the physical situation you are dealing with.

Some coordinates are more useful sometimes because they can simplify a problem dramatically. Usually it is clear from the symmetries of the problem which coordinates to use. Examples:

1)cylindrical coordinates: Coaxial cables, wires, solenoids...

2)Spherical coordinates: spherically symmetric problems, suchs as point charge in origin, spherical shells...